# "ImportError: No module named" in python 2.7.17

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I'm using python installed in a loc
My file structure is set up as following

```
adsb_comm
     msg
          adsb.msg
          flarm.msg
          flighttracking.msg
     src
          __init__.py
          main.py
          test.py
     __init__.py
     CMakeLists.txt
     package.xml
```

I try to import the messages for my code follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from adsb_comm.msg import adsb, flarm, flightTracking
```

When writing code, VSC recognizes this perfectly but when I try to run the code, it always results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joren/catkin_ws/src/adsb_comm/src/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Parser import adsbMod, flarmMod, statMod
  File "/home/joren/catkin_ws/src/adsb_comm/src/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from adsb_comm.msg import adsb, flarm, flightTracking
ImportError: No module named adsb_comm.msg
```

When I ran

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

I got

```
['', '/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/joren/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3']
```

But I am not certain what to make of this.
I also tried using a relative import instead, along the lines of

```
from ..msg import adsb
```

but got a value error

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: have you tried just `from adsb_comm import adsb, flarm, flightTracking` removing the extension of the file '.msg' ?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect to be able to import Python code from a file with a `.msg` extension. What does that extension even mean?

Comment: @BenoitDrogou in the code, the `.msg` refers to the `msg` subdirectory of `adsb_comm`, not the file extension.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time answer your question?

Comment: that first '.msg' is just the folder in which the msg files are located. Removing it gives me `ImportError: No module named adsb_comm`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the .msg files are required for ROS. [link](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CustomMessagePublisherSubscriber%28python%29) if you're interested. The problem wasn't with the extension but with the fact that ROS had not been properly sourced.